AP3012 Running away with current draw
I am using Diodes AP3012 to boost Li ion battery voltage up to 5V. I have a I2C LED driver to drive LEDS. When I get current draw on the output of my boost converter, the output of the boost converter runs away to 14V every time. Any help would be appreciated.



Your feedback pin is sensing the output of the switch (which is rapidly switching up and down) rather than the output of the converter as a whole.  Move the sense pin to measure the voltage across the output capacitor.
Additionally, you diagram shows no input capacitor on the converter.  You should add one close by as otherwise you'll be injecting high frequency switching noise into the rest of the system and possibly undermine the working of the device.

You are a savior. Didnt even notice I picked up the feedback on the wrong node. Always helps to have another set of eyes on things. Thank you very much!

Move your diode between the feedback resistors and the inductor as shown in the datasheet. Also you should add an input filtering capacitor (C1)

source: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/176175/BCDSEMI/AP3012.html
